# Parsing JSON files from a column with invalid token in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

This is the JSON File:

```
{"success":false,"error":{"type":"ValidationError","message":{"Period":{"maxValue:$1":"Value"}}}}
```

I am trying to parse the "Value" from the file

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(response,"$.error.message.loanPeriod.maxValue:$1']")
```

The tricky part is because of the "$" or the ":" from "maxValue:$1"

Please note that "response" is the column

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow!  Could you be a bit more clear and edit your post,  I don't know what your question is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

In cases where a JSON key uses invalid JSONPath characters, you can escape those characters using single quotes and brackets as in example below

```
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(response,"$.error.message.Period['maxValue:$1']")
```

See more in documentation - [JSON Functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_or_json_extract_scalar)