# dynamic split json string in bigquery

Tags: sql, json, string, google-bigquery

I am new to big query and want to split the "properties" column values into separate columns. The column is formatted in string
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRjZE.png)

```
with 
cte as (
    select 
        event, 
        json_value(properties,'$.distinct_id') as distinct_id, 
        json_value(properties,'$.time') as time,
        json_value(properties,'$.app_version_string') as app_version_string, 
        json_value(properties,'$.app_build_number') as app_build_number, 
        json_value(properties,'$.user_id') as user_id, from `mixpanel.event_data`
) 
select * from cte
```

I tried the above code but all I am getting are nulls.
The demo result that i want is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txw2W.png)

How would I go about this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hope these are helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829978/parsing-json-files-from-a-column-with-invalid-token-in-bigquery  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985237/how-to-extract-values-from-a-column-google-big-quey

Comment: use **json_value(properties, '$."$app_version_string"')** instead